# How to add functions from custom JARs to EMR cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, livy

I created an EMR cluster on AWS with Spark and Livy. I submitted a custom JAR with some additional libraries (e.g. datasources for custom formats) as a custom JAR step. However, the stuff from the custom JAR is not available when I try to access it from Livy.

What do I have to do to make the custom stuff available in the environment?

Comment: Is it available in your Spark job?

Comment: In my Spark job, I add it as a dependency and `sbt assembly` packs it into the fat JAR. I want to include a library my colleagues can use when they use Spark with Livy.

Comment: You need to make sure you add it to their jobs via `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` properties to the `spark-submit`.

Comment: Ah, so I should handle this via the classifications JSON I can supply when creating the cluster?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I don't remember the specific details but you can definitely provide custom configuration.

Comment: I am currently trying to use bootstrap actions to copy my library to the nodes in conjunction with configuration classifications. Let's see if that works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer to be able to accept it - I figured it out thanks to Yuval Itzchakov's comments and the AWS documentation on Custom Bootstrap Actions.

So here is what I did:

1. I put my library jar (a fat jar created with `sbt assembly` containing everything needed) into an S3 bucket
2. Created a script named `copylib.sh` which contains the following:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash

   mkdir -p /home/hadoop/mylib
   aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mylib.jar /home/hadoop/mylib
   ```
3. Created the following configuration JSON and put it into the same bucket besides the `mylib.jar` and `copylib.sh`:

   ```
   [{
      "configurations": [{
          "classification": "export",
          "properties": {
              "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
      }],
      "classification": "spark-env",
      "properties": {}
   }, {
      "configurations": [{
          "classification": "export",
          "properties": {
              "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
      }],
      "classification": "yarn-env",
      "properties": {}
   },
   {
      "Classification": "spark-defaults",
      "Properties": {
          "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar:/home/hadoop/mylib/mylib.jar",
          "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar:/home/hadoop/mylib/mylib.jar"
      }
   }
   ]
   ```

   The classifications for `spark-env` and `yarn-env` are needed for PySpark to work with Python3 on EMR through Livy. And there is another issue: EMR already populates the two `extraClassPath`s with a lot of libraries which are needed for EMR to function properly, so I had to run a cluster without my lib, extract these settings from `spark-defaults.conf` and adjust my classification afterwards. Otherwise, things like S3 access wouldn't work.
4. When creating the cluster, in Step 1 I referenced the configuration JSON file from above in `Edit software settings`, and in Step 3, I configured `copylib.sh` as a Custom Bootstrap Action.

I can now open the Jupyterhub of the cluster, start a notebook and work with my added functions.

Answer (score 1):

I use an alternative way that does not use a bootstrap action.

1. Place the JARs in S3
2. Pass them in the `--jars` option of `spark-submit` eg. `spark-submit --jars s3://my-bucket/extra-jars/*.jar`. All the jars will be copied to the cluster.

This way we can use any jar from s3 if we missed to add bootstrap action during cluster creation.